# Start activity instead of fragment in tabhost

Tags: android

I want to know if there is a way that I start an activity instead of launching a fragment on tabhost tab select.

What I want to acomplish if to launch an activity where the user can write a post and then save, why I want this? because when I want to edit I launch an activity and I don't want to have 2 classes that do the same thing with a little difference, and also the tab on the bottom uses so much space that leave my form area tiny.

My code actually looks like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedBundleState) {
    mTabHost.setup(getBaseContext(), getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
    // This starts the HomeFragment
    mTabHost.addTab(newTabSpec("tabHome", R.layout.tab_home), HomeFragment.class, null);
    // This throws an error
    mTabHost.addTab(newTabSpec("tabPost", R.layout.tab_post));
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}

private TabSpec newTabSpec(String tag, int layout) {
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layout, null);
    return mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(view);
}

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    if (tabId == "tabAddPublication") {
        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), PostActivity.class));
    }
}
```

I got this error

```
you must specify a way to create a tab content
```

Regards

Comment: I may sound silly but can you not make an `Intent` to that activity from the fragment?I am not sure about starting an `Activity` instead of `Fragment`.

Comment: I just want to launch an activity and no other action take, its similar to just click on a tab and do nothing on the fragment container, only launch the activity. dunno if is possible or how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Documents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setContent(android.content.Intent))

> public TabHost.TabSpec setContent (Intent intent)
>     Specify an intent to use to launch an activity as the tab content.

You need to set the content for `TabSpec`

```
Intent postActivityIntent = new Intent(this, PostActivity.class);
mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setContent(postActivityIntent);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: seems that Im forced to use fragments here, all the methods to use TabHost in Activity, ActvityGroup or TabActivity are deprecated so it will be removed soon, damn, I hate fragments. but I'll accept your answer because it is correct

Comment: By seeing your question itself one can say that you hate fragments. :D :)

Comment: I don't like the way that you play arround with fragments, to me te code still much clean when using activities, you cannot use this when starting and activity or when you want to read some resources you need to call getActivity().getResources()... and you need to write more instead of write less! don't know if google engineers like this way or apple way, where you code need to be nice too ;)